# How do i change panda dataframe to JSON to plot data in dygraphs?

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe, dygraphs

So I need to change my panda dataframe to JSON to plot in dygraphs. The data looks like this :

```
Date        Open    High     Low    Close      Volume                                        
2004-08-19  100.01  104.06   95.96  100.335  44659000.0    
2004-08-20  101.01  109.08  100.50  108.310  22834300.0         
2004-08-23  110.76  113.48  109.05  109.400  18256100.0          
2004-08-24  111.24  111.60  103.57  104.870  15247300.0          
2004-08-25  104.76  108.00  103.88  106.000   9188600.0
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you need the json constructed?  My guess is you probably want each row as a record, either with or without the index number.  Try:

```
df.to_json(orient='records')
```

or

```
df.to_json(orient='index')
```

If you want the columns headers as keys and the column data as values in the json output, you can use:

```
df.to_json(orient='columns')
```

Comment: Ive tried to look through dygraphs documentations; I think the format i need it to be in is:

"Date,Temperature\n" +
    "2008-05-07,75\n" +
    "2008-05-08,70\n" +
    "2008-05-09,80\n" 

However later i might need it to be formatted like:
(0, 0), (.1, .2), (.3, .1), (.5, 1), (.8, .6), (1, 1.08), (1.3, 1.1), (2, 3.23), (2.43, 2) where all the value are not dates.

Comment: So ive had a look at pandas documentation (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-json-writer) and ive found setting:

dfopen=df.to_json(orient='values') gets me to [1492300800000,141.91,142.38,141.05,141.05],[1491696000000,143.73,144.18,143.27,143.34]